# How can I get the MAX(total) with the whole row and its data? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have table with billings have some of columns like (order number, date, and total) I want to get the MAX(total) in specific date with whole row and its data.

Here is the table:
[Click here to show the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyJlk.jpg)

I have already wrote some line in MySQL but it came with some mistake

```
SELECT * FROM biling WHERE total=(SELECT MAX(total) FROM biling WHERE date='2021-10-26')
```

Let's say the part two of this query equals `50` it came with the maximum billing indeed but what if there is more than one row with the same of MAX(total) in this day I Just want to calculate just one row.

I hope you getting my point guys. And thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or unexpected result? Please clarify exactly what the problem is when you run this code.

Comment: Not an error, it's an unexpected result but just in case; I have same maximum total

Comment: define an or unse also the3 date in the where clause and limit to 1

Comment: It came with different row I need the max total where date = 2021-10-26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `LIMIT 1` to the end of your select seems to be the solution.
Updated!
The simple solution that is needed is

```
SELECT * FROM biling WHERE date='2021-10-26' ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It came with different row I need the max total where date = 2021-10-26

Comment: SELECT * FROM biling WHERE date='2021-10-26' order by total desc limit 1
Like this?

Comment: Exactly. Thank you very much man, I'm really appreciated.